# What version of sitecore jss is compatible with a given sitecore-jss npm package

Tags: jss, npm

I am trying to find some sort of compatibility matrix that will tell me what version of JSS https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_JavaScript_Services/ is compatible with the sitecore-jss npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss
At the moment we are locked into JSS 13 due to our Sitecore version (9.3), but I'm trying to see if I can bump our sitecore-jss npm package past 13.0.

Where can I find some documentation linking Sitecore package versions with npm package versions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### NPM to JSS version

I may have misunderstood part of the question, but from my understanding, the NPM version and the JSS version are the same thing, so the compatibility matches the NPM version. This means if JSS 13 is what is compatible with your version, then you should be using NPM version 13.

### Compatibility by Sitecore XP version

You can review the compatibility of JSS up to version 9.3 on this compatibility document: https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0541788

From that doc, these are the compatibility of JSS versions up to 9.3:

- **JSS 9.0 Tech Preview:** 9.0
- **JSS 11.0:** 9.0, 9.1
- **JSS 12.0:** 9.2
- **JSS 13.0:** 9.3
- **JSS 14.0:** Not compatible with 9.3

For versions after 9.3, you can review this article: https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB1000576

From that doc, JSS version compatibility is as follows:

- **JSS 14.0:** 10.0
- **JSS 15.0:** 10.0
- **JSS 16.0:** 10.1
- **JSS 18.0:** 10.1
- **JSS 19.0:** 10.2

**Note on JSS vs Headless Services**
With Headless Services it is more than just JSS and now includes ASP.NET Core as well. Newer releases are referred to as Headless Services instead of JSS. You can find the downloads for Headless Services here: dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Headless_Rendering.aspx

Comment: It looks like sitecore renamed JSS to Headless Services after JSS 15?
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/190/sitecore-headless-development/sitecore-headless-services.html
That's why i can't find a download for JSS 19, which made me wonder if the npm & sitecore packages shared versions

Comment: Exactly, with Headless Services it is more than just JSS and now includes ASP.NET Core as well. You can find the downloads for Headless Services here: https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Headless_Rendering.aspx

Comment: Accepting this answer, though the comment section is really what solves this question. Thanks!

Comment: I added the note on the Headless Services downloads to the answer. Glad that helped!

Comment: When analyzing the content of the provided link https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB1000576 , it indicates that there is no JSS tickmark mentioned. This raises the question of whether this absence signifies that the 10.3 JSS is pre-installed.

Comment: @SunilRana: Can you clarify what you mean? That page does have a checkmark for 10.3 and JSS 21.x?