# Which JSS version for Sitecore 10.2?

Tags: sxa, jss, sxa-jss

I am trying to setup a JSS app on Sitecore 10.2 (with SXA) but that is not going as expected.

I checked the [downloads page for Headless Rendering](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Headless_Rendering.aspx) and that mentions version 20.0.2 as latest now compatible with Sitecore 10.2. This install went fine. Creating a headless site with SXA seems to have worked and our graphQL playground is working.

I assumed that for the actual front-end app I had to use the same version (https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/30563/237 confirms that) so I used "`npx create-sitecore-jss@ver20 --templates nextjs,nextjs-sxa ...`"  to do a setup and that created a nextjs app for me. Did the rest of the setup and config deploys and that seemed to go well - but when I start the site I get an error: `Cannot query field "site" on type "Query"`.

Apparently the RedirectsQuery is doing a graphQL query for "sites" which is not supported. If I try that in my graphQL-UI it is indeed not in the schema. It is as from 10.3 however.

So now I'm thinking I have some wrong version somewhere.. so the question is actually if anyone has an idea what version I should be using on a Sitecore 10.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the version what not the issue - but the parameters. Including `nextjs-sxa` appears to be only supported for XMCloud. Found that in some well hidden docs - although I must admit that if you don't use it you are asked to include it and it is very clearly mentioned in that case.

Lesson learned: use lesser parameters in the creation command and let the questions come to you..

Answer (score 1):

- Yes for **Sitecore 10.2** compatible version is version 20.0.2 which you
  are using. Check your frontend app if it has the same version. Try
  to uninstall the current version using the following command:

  **npm uninstall -g @sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli**
- Then install the latest version:

  **npm install -g @sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli@20.0.2**
- Then create your app --

  **npx create-sitecore-jss --templates nextjs --appName my-nextjs-app --fetchWith GraphQL**

Comment: Checked all that - versions all seem fine. The CLI is the correct version and the app was created with a ver20 tag which is version 20.1.3 today (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli?activeTab=versions)

Comment: For both frontend and the package version should be 20.0.2

Comment: And how would I do that? I can only use the tags on the frontend and if I take the tag for version 20 it is 20.1.3. Unless I'm missing something there (which is possible as I'm no npm expert)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I apologize for any confusion that my previous message may have caused. To determine the proper version of JSS to use, I would recommend checking the documentation of the specific library or framework you are using. They will usually have recommendations for the compatible version of JSS. Additionally, it's always a good idea to keep your dependencies up-to-date to avoid any potential security vulnerabilities. Here's a helpful link to get started:https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli/v/20.0.2

Answer (score 0):

With Sitecore Headless Rendering version 20, you can install NextJS SXA, which is only compatible with XM cloud. It is mentioned when you install it using the command:

```
npx create-sitecore-jss@ver20
```

It will ask if you would like to include any add-on initializers:

```
Would you like to include any add-on initializers? (Press <space> to select, <a> to toggle all, <i> to invert selection, and <enter> to proceed)
 ( ) nextjs-styleguide - Includes example components and setup for working disconnected
>(*) nextjs-sxa - Includes example components and setup for SXA Headless (only compatible with Sitecore XM Cloud)
```

[image]

On the other hand, With version 21, you will get much more options. You can choose  nextjs-sxa, it will include example components and setup for Headless SXA projects which is even compatible with non XM cloud headless setup.

```
 Would you like to include any add-on initializers? (Press <space> to select, <a> to toggle all, <i> to invert selection, and <enter> to proceed)
>( ) nextjs-styleguide - Includes example components and setup for working disconnected
 ( ) nextjs-styleguide-tracking - Includes example (Sitecore XP) tracking component
 ( ) nextjs-sxa - Includes example components and setup for Headless SXA projects
 ( ) nextjs-personalize - Includes example setup for projects using XM Cloud Embedded Personalization
 ( ) nextjs-multisite - Includes example setup for hosting multiple sites in a single NextJS application
```

[image]

Comment: But version 21 is not compatible with 10.2 - right?

Comment: As per this documentation, version 21 is not compatible with 10.2 https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB1000576